# What does Drew Pritchard from the TV show Salvage Hunters mean when he uses the word tactile?

Tags: meaning, british-english

Different dictionaries define it as of something you can touch or something that is connected with the sense of touch. However, this does not make sense to me. He buys antiques. Everything he buys can be touched. What then makes some things tactile and others not?
I can give a few examples of him using the word. Those are from season 9, episode 5.

https://youtu.be/hqrs3xyH6h0?t=2029

https://youtu.be/hqrs3xyH6h0?t=2165

Answer (score 1):

He seems to be implying that there is used, worn, but solid feeling to the piece. It seems like he is implying that there is a difference that can be felt, an amount of wear and tear that one can sense through touching it. It's the standard definition of tactile, just imbued with his own preconceptions he's attached to the word.

Comment: This broadened sense is not covered in most online dictionaries. I hope OED lists it, as it's certainly in use.